# Php POST - get boundary value

Tags: php, post, curl, plupload

So I want to upload a file using curl, but the problem is: the post request contains a boundary variable that is checked upon by the website. I know this because I get errors when modifying this variable in Tamper Data.

Http headers (important part):

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----pluploadboundaryp18mu3sf5fus08pd11c3kvq163514
```

Post request:

```
------pluploadboundaryp18mu3sf5fus08pd11c3kvq163514\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n
\r\n
1.jpg\r\n
------pluploadboundaryp18mu3sf5fus08pd11c3kvq163514\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imageData"; filename="1.jpg"\r\n
Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n
\r\n
{Filecontent}
```

So my question is: How can I bypass or duplicate this boundary?

Edit: if you want to test yourself the form upload is located at:https://www.marktplaats.nl/syi/239/1399/plaatsAdvertentie.html

Comment: Why do you need to modify it at all? Normally curl should handle those values automatically and you should not bother about it. It seems you are misusing the curl in some way.

Comment: I must admit im not totally sure either what to do.. It shouldnt be the cookie or the XSRF token because i made sure those were right (login works with cookie and XSRF token). The main thing is when im trying to upload i get a error

Comment: I am facing similar issues, could you please explain how did you resolve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

So i got the answer on my question. Also thanks to Ruslan Bes for helping.
The problem was i sended my post request as http_build_query($post) instead of $post.
Small mistakes can cause a lot of problems :D

Comment: I am facing similar issues, could you please explain how did you resolve the problem ?